# Format cell if today is 2 weeks after date in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

Basically trying to do the following with conditional formatting

Format A2 IF TODAY is >= Date in A1+14.

So if the date in A1 was two weeks ago or more, I need A2 to switch to a fill color.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out!

```
=A1:A <= today() - 14
```